# Listing files and directories returns mixed case sensitivity on the results. Is there a way to force case sensitive results?

Tags: dropbox-api, dropbox-php

I've created a folder structure as below, with some images in the subfolders.

```
Test 1
    Test 2.1
        Test 2.1.1
        Test 2.1.2
    Test 2.2
```

When calling 'getMetadataWithChildren' I seem to be having mixed case results returned such as:

```
Array
(
    [hash] => fd2934448f39ea3aa37faca9bbf72beb
    [revision] => 14666
    [rev] => 394a08b41a0c
    [thumb_exists] =>
    [bytes] => 0
    [modified] => Thu, 10 Jul 2014 11:18:25 +0000
    [path] => /Test 1/Test 2.1
    [is_dir] => 1
    [icon] => folder
    [root] => dropbox
    [contents] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [revision] => 14672
                    [rev] => 395008b41a0c
                    [thumb_exists] => 1
                    [bytes] => 879394
                    [modified] => Thu, 10 Jul 2014 11:18:25 +0000
                    [client_mtime] => Tue, 14 Jul 2009 05:32:31 +0000
                    [path] => /test 1/Test 2.1/Chrysanthemum.jpg
                    [is_dir] =>
                    [icon] => page_white_picture
                    [root] => dropbox
                    [mime_type] => image/jpeg
                    [size] => 858.8 KB
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [revision] => 14670
                    [rev] => 394e08b41a0c
                    [thumb_exists] =>
                    [bytes] => 0
                    [modified] => Thu, 10 Jul 2014 11:18:25 +0000
                    [path] => /test 1/Test 2.1/Test 2.1.1
                    [is_dir] => 1
                    [icon] => folder
                    [root] => dropbox
                    [size] => 0 bytes
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [revision] => 14671
                    [rev] => 394f08b41a0c
                    [thumb_exists] =>
                    [bytes] => 0
                    [modified] => Thu, 10 Jul 2014 11:18:25 +0000
                    [path] => /test 1/Test 2.1/Test 2.1.2
                    [is_dir] => 1
                    [icon] => folder
                    [root] => dropbox
                    [size] => 0 bytes
                )

        )


    [size] => 0 bytes
)
```

Note that in the 'contents' array, the path is not the same as the path provided (and as named in my Dropbox).  I need the results to be the correct case sensitivity for grouping them in my application so am I missing something simple or is this an issue with the Dropbox API and the results that are returned?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Dropbox itself is actually case insensitive. You can find more information here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/bestpractices https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=110696

Comment: I appreciate that Dropbox is case insensitive as per the documentation however I would expect that if a directory or file is called "Test" then it would return that rather than changing it to "test".  I've done a few more tests and it always appears to do this when reaching a depth of 3 i.e. a -> B -> C.